# Using Ubuntu One to synchronise htdocs?

Tags: ubuntu-one, xampp

I'm new to Linux. I've got XAMPP installed on Ubuntu 10.10 in `/opt/lampp/`.

I'd like to synchronise the files in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` with Ubuntu One (and I've bought 20gb in preparation), but there's no option to sync the folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to be able to synchronise the directory with Ubuntu One, you need to a) own the directory, and b) have it inside your home directory (or a sub-directory of your home directory):

1. Just create a directory inside of your home directory, and name it, for example, `public_http`. Then **change xampps default directory** inside it's `httpd.conf` file.

   or
2. You can also remove the htdocs directory, create one named `public_html` in your home directory and use

   ```
   sudo ln -s ~/public_html /opt/lampp/htdocs
   ```

   To create a **[Symbolic Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) named `/opt/lampp/htdocs`**, that **points to `~/public_html`** (note: it doesn't work the other way 'round, ubuntu one will not let you synchronise a directory if it is a symlink that points to a real directory).

   This means that whenever the system tries to look for a file inside the /opt/lampp/htdocs directory, it is secretly and silenty 'redirected' to your home directory.

Afterwards, you can tell Ubuntu One to synchronise the directory as you normally would:

[image]