# Change XAMPP's htdocs web root folder to another one

Tags: permissions, apache2, webserver, xampp

I'm trying to change the `XAMPP`'s web root default directory `/opt/lampp/htdocs` to another one like `/home/me/Dropbox/public_html` without success.

I've edited the file `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

```
# old line: DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "/home/me/Dropbox/public_html"

#...etc...

# old line: <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
<Directory "/home/me/Dropbox/Work/public_html">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
# etc...
```

I've did this as said in this article: [Using Ubuntu One to synchronise htdocs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19676/using-ubuntu-one-to-synchronise-htdocs)

Then I've restarted `Apache` and I've got a permission error `403` on every page I've called with the web browser.

So I've changed folder and files permission to `755`.

I've did this as said in this article: 
[What file permissions should I set on web root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9402/what-file-permissions-should-i-set-on-web-root)

The problem still remains the same, I have the `403` error on every page I try to reach with the web browser.

I have the same problem on a `Mac` using `XAMPP`.

So everythig works fine if the folder remains the original `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.

How can I change it correctly?

Comment: I can't find the opt folder, is it inside of another folder or something?
I've already searched almost the whole xampp installation folder and can't find it, please help :(

Comment: I've did it on a `Ubuntu` distribution, maybe are you using another distro? Starting from the root folder `/` I'll find the `opt` folder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`
change **nobody** and nogroup

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User nobody
Group nogroup
</IfModule>
```

to your username and your group

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue and here is what i did:

Run this command to stop xampp:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

Open `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

Change **your_folder** to the folder you wanna use

```
 DocumentRoot "/home/username/your_folder"
 <Directory "/home/username/your_folder">
```

Change `User` & `Group` value from `daemon` to:

```
User nobody
Group nogroup
```

set chmod to **your_folder** with this command

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/username/your_folder
```

Save the file and start xampp with this command:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Open your browser and enter this url:

```
http://localhost/your_folder/
```

Done, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on user group type in `httpd.conf` file which must be set to `staff` and then I don't need to change the folder permissions on the folder i'd like to use as web root.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolic link

```
ln -s /home/username/public_html/ /opt/lampp/yoursymlink
```

with your username "~username" as symbolic link so you can keep the same URL location

`localhost/~username` for files like if your were using default Apache server and not XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this so that you can create files in htdocs folder then Just navigate to opt/lampp and then open in terminal and write

> sudo chmod 777 htdocs/

Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem under linux 18.3. None of the above worked exactly as described, but the following combination did:

In the file /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf I made the following changes:

Replace:

```
    <IfModule unixd_module>
    User daemon 
    Group daemon
    </IfModule>
```

by:

```
    <IfModule unixd_module>
    User myusername 
    Group myusername
    </IfModule>
```

and further down replace:

```
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
```

by

```
    DocumentRoot "/home/myusername/webdir" 
    <Directory "/home/myusername/webdir"
```

Thereby, "myusername" is my linux username, and "webdir" is the directory name in my home directory where the php-files are stored.

In the terminal, stop lampp before saving the file, start again. In the browser localhost will then point to "webdir".

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it following the steps bellow:

1. First install xampp by following steps

   ```
   $ sudo cd Downloads && sudo chmod a+x ./your-downloaded-xampp-file.run && sudo ./your-downloaded-xampp-file.run
   ```
2. Change file owner of /opt/lampp directory. username should be the username of your new documentroot folder ownername

   ```
   sudo chown -hR  username:root /opt/lampp
   ```
3. edit `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`

   ```
   sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
   ```
4. edit your document root path to mounted windows documentroot and  the following lines

   ```
   <IfModule unixd_module>
      User nobody
      Group nogroup
   </IfModule>
   ```
5. restart xampp. And you will find forbidden error has gone

Answer (score -1):

In NTFS format you can't set folder permissions. Open `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`.

Edit
User *computerName*
Group *computerName*

And after that you can access the symbolic links in htdocs.

Comment: Where is `NTFS format` told in the question? Also the rest of the answer does not seem to answer the OP's question.

Answer (score -2):

Just make an index file on your new `htdocs` folder.

Comment: Can you edit this to provide some details explaining how to do that?

Comment: not understandable what he tried to explain just in one line

Comment: More instructions would be very helpful.